# Ask a step on the proof which is relevant on the span of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathscr S$ be a subspace of $\mathbb R^p$, and let G be positive semidefinite such that $\operatorname{span}(G) \subset \mathscr S$. The following statements are equivalent:

1. there is a basis $v_1,...,v_d$ of $\mathscr S$ such that $V^T GV>0$, where V is the $p\times d$ matrix ($v_1,...,v_d$);
2. for all $\nu \in \mathscr S, \nu \neq 0,$ we have $\nu^T G \nu >0$;

Proof. $2 \Rightarrow 1$. If statement 1 is not true, then there is a $w \in \mathbb R^d, w \neq 0$, such that $w^T V^T GVw=0$. (my explanation: G is already positive semidefinite, so it is impossible to get $w^T V^T GVw<0$). So $\nu^T G \nu=0$ for $\nu=Vw$.

Because V is a basis matrix of $\mathscr S$, $w \in \mathscr S$, and $w \neq 0$, we have $Vw \neq 0$. Hence statement 2 is not true.

Question: In the above, I know V is a basis matrix of $\mathscr S$, but how to see $w \in \mathscr S$? I only see $w \in \mathbb R^d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to see $w\in\mathcal{S}$.
The vector which gives the contradiction is $\nu$, which is in $\mathcal{S}$ because is a linear combination of the basis of $\mathcal{S}$ $\{v_1,...,v_d\}$ and it is different from $0$ as you have correctly pointed out.

Comment: Thank you! There's a follow-up question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4835541/ask-a-step-on-the-proof-on-the-span-of-a-matrix-is-equal-to-some-subspace