# Ask a step on the proof on the span of a matrix is equal to some subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathscr S$ be a subspace of $\mathbb R^p$, and let G be positive semidefinite such that $\operatorname{span}(G) \subset \mathscr S$. The following statements are equivalent:

1. there is a basis $v_1,...,v_d$ of $\mathscr S$ such that $V^T GV>0$, where V is the $p\times d$ matrix ($v_1,...,v_d$);
2. for all $\nu \in \mathscr S, \nu \neq 0,$ we have $\nu^T G \nu >0$;
3. $\operatorname{span}(G) = \mathscr S$.

Proof. $2 \Rightarrow 1$. If statement 1 is not true, then there is a $w \in \mathbb R^d, w \neq 0$, such that $w^T V^T GVw=0$. So $\nu^T G \nu=0$ for $\nu=Vw$. Because V is a basis matrix of $\mathscr S$, $\nu \in \mathscr S$, and $w \neq 0$, we have $Vw = \nu \neq 0$. Hence statement 2 is not true.

$1 \Rightarrow 2$. Let $\nu \in \mathscr S, \nu \neq 0$. Then $\nu = \sum\limits_{i=1}^d \alpha_i \nu_i$, where $||\alpha|| \neq 0, \alpha$ being the vector $(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_d)^T$. Hence

$$\nu^T G \nu=\alpha^T (V^T GV) \alpha>0.$$

Thus statement 2 holds.

But the book didn't give a correct proof of 2 and 3. It says:

$2 \Rightarrow 3$. If statement 2 is not true then there exists $\nu \in \mathscr S, \nu \neq 0$, such that $\nu^T G \nu=0$. So statement 1 is not true.

$3 \Rightarrow 2$. If statement 2 is not true then there exists $\nu \in \mathscr S, \nu \neq 0$, such that $\nu^T G \nu=0$. Then $\nu \perp \operatorname{span}(G)$ and statement 2 is not true.

Obviously there are mistakes and typos in the proof between 2 and 3.

**Question:** how to prove $2 \Rightarrow 3$ and $3 \Rightarrow 2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer requires some basic knowledge on inner product. You should know the fact that $A\oplus A^{\perp}=V$, a basic fact on real-inner product space. It is lengthy but detailed. I claim I have left *no gaps* as exercise for you to fill. However, do not hesitate to ask if anything is explained in an unclear way.

---

**Answer**

It is a basic fact that, since $G$ is positive semidefinite, exists $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ invertible, s.t.
\begin{equation*}
G=C^T \mathrm{diag}\{\overbrace{1,\cdots,1}^{\text{first $r$ components}},0,\cdots,0\}C,
\end{equation*}
where $r=\mathrm{rank} G$.
To compute, we write $C=(a_ij)_{n\times n}$ as row vectors:
\begin{equation*}
C=\begin{pmatrix}
\vec{v}_1 \\ 
\vec{v}_2 \\ 
\cdots \\ 
\vec{v}_n
\end{pmatrix} .
\end{equation*}
(Since it is easy to mistaken $v_i$ as real numbers in the following, we temporarily add vector symbols for vectors.)

**Claim** 1: $\vec{x}^TG\vec{x}=0\iff$ $\vec{x}$ is orthogonal to $\vec{v}_i$, $1\le i\le r$.

Proof:
For $\vec{x}=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ 
\cdots \\ 
x_n
\end{pmatrix} $,
we have
\begin{equation*}
C\vec{x}=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+\cdots+a_{1n}x_n \\ 
\cdots \\ 
a_{n1}x_1+a_{n2}x_2+\cdots+a_{nn}x_n
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
\vec{v}_1\cdot \vec{x} \\ 
\cdots \\ 
\vec{v}_n\cdot \vec{x}
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation*}
Right multiplication with $\mathrm{diag}\{1,\cdots,1,0,\cdots,0\}$ vanishes the last $n-r$ rows:
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{diag}\{1,\cdots,1,0,\cdots,0\}C\vec{x}=\begin{pmatrix}
\vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{x} \\ 
\cdots \\ 
\vec{v}_r\cdot\vec{x} \\ 
0 \\ 
\cdots \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation*}
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\vec{x}^TG\vec{x}=& \vec{x}^TC^T \mathrm{diag}\{1,\cdots,1,0,\cdots,0\}  C\vec{x}\\
=& \vec{x}^TC^T \mathrm{diag}\{1,\cdots,1,0,\cdots,0\} \mathrm{diag}\{1,\cdots,1,0,\cdots,0\}  C\vec{x}\\
=& (\mathrm{diag}\{1,\cdots,1,0,\cdots,0\}  C\vec{x})^T \mathrm{diag}\{1,\cdots,1,0,\cdots,0\}  C\vec{x}\\
=&(\vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{x} , \cdots , \vec{v}_r\cdot\vec{x} , 0, \cdots, 0)\begin{pmatrix}
\vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{x} \\ 
\cdots \\ 
\vec{v}_r\cdot\vec{x} \\ 
0 \\ 
\cdots \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}\\
=&\mid\mid(\vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{x} , \cdots , \vec{v}_r\cdot\vec{x} , 0, \cdots, 0)
\mid\mid^2.
\end{align*}
That is, $\vec{x}^TG\vec{x}=0\iff$ $\vec{x}$ is orthogonal to $\vec{v}_i$, $1\le i\le r$.

**Claim 1 is verified.**

From now on we remove the vector symbol.

**Claim 2**: $\mathrm{span}(G)=\mathrm{span}({v}_1,\cdots,{v}_r)$.

Proof:
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{diag}\{1,\cdots,1,0,\cdots,0\}  C        =\begin{pmatrix}
        v_1 \\ 
        \cdots \\ 
        v_r\\
        0\\
        \cdots\\
        0
        \end{pmatrix} .
\end{equation*}

Therefore

\begin{align*}
G=&C^T \mathrm{diag}\{1,\cdots,1,0,\cdots,0\}  C\\
=& C^T \mathrm{diag}\{1,\cdots,1,0,\cdots,0\} \mathrm{diag}\{1,\cdots,1,0,\cdots,0\}   C\\
=&(\mathrm{diag}\{1,\cdots,1,0,\cdots,0\}C )^T\mathrm{diag}\{1,\cdots,1,0,\cdots,0\}   C\\
=&(v_1^T,\cdots,v_r^T,0,\cdots,0 )^T \begin{pmatrix}
v_1 \\ 
\cdots \\ 
v_r\\
0\\
\cdots\\
0
\end{pmatrix} \\
=&  \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{r1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
a_{12} &  & a_{r2} & \vdots &  & \cdots \\ 
\cdots &  & \cdots &  &  &  \\ 
a_{1n} &  & a_{rn} & 0 &  & 0
\end{pmatrix}    \begin{pmatrix}
v_1 \\ 
\cdots \\ 
v_r\\
0\\
\cdots\\
0
\end{pmatrix}. 
\end{align*}
Therefore the row vectors of $G=C^T \mathrm{diag}\{1,\cdots,1,0,\cdots,0\}  C$ consists of
\begin{align*}
&a_{11}v_1+\cdots+a_{r1}v_r\\
&\cdots\\
&a_{1i}v_1+\cdots+a_{ri}v_r\\
&\cdots\\
&a_{1n}v_1+\cdots+a_{rn}v_r.
\end{align*}
The row space of $G$ is spanned by these $n$ vectors.

Since
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{r1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
a_{12} &  & a_{r2} & \vdots &  & \cdots \\ 
\cdots &  & \cdots &  &  &  \\ 
a_{1n} &  & a_{rn} & 0 &  & 0
\end{pmatrix}  
\end{equation*}
has rank $r$, the $n$ vectors above has rank $r$, and therefore the row space of $G$ has dimension $r$.
Since $\mathrm{span}({v}_1,\cdots,{v}_r)$ contains the row space of $G$ (obvious) and has dimension $r$ (by hypothesis $\mathrm{rank} G=r$), they must be equal.

**Thus we infer claim 2.**

So to prove $(2)\iff (3)$, it suffices to prove: (*The reason why this "it suffices to prove" holds is added at the end of the answer.*)

> Let $W$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, ${v}_1,\cdots,{v}_r$ are $r$ ($r\le n$) linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. "$\mathrm{span}({v}_1,\cdots,{v}_r)$ is contained in $W$ properly (i.e. $\mathrm{span}({v}_1,\cdots,{v}_r)\subseteq W$, $\mathrm{span}({v}_1,\cdots,{v}_r)\ne W$)" $\iff$ "exists $0\ne w\in W$, $w$ is orthogonal to ${v}_i$, $1\le i\le r$".

Now we show the above statement. Denote $A=\mathrm{span}({v}_1,\cdots,{v}_r)$.

$(\implies)$: Select $x\in W-A$. ($W-A\ne\varnothing$ since $A\subseteq W$ strictly.) Write
\begin{equation*}
x=x_1+x_2, \ \ x_1\in A,\ x_2\in A^{\perp}.
\end{equation*}
Then $x_2=x-x_1\in W$ since $x\in W$ and $x_1\in A\subseteq W$.
$x_2$ is non-zero (since $x\notin A\implies x\ne x_1$), in $W$ and orthogonal to ${v}_1,\cdots,{v}_r$.

$(\impliedby)$: $w\in A^{\perp}$, $w\ne 0$ and $A\cap A^{\perp}=\{0\}$ $\implies$ $w\notin A$.

---

The reason that $(2)\iff (3)$ is reduced to the statement in the quoted block:

Suppose the statement in the quoted block is verified. Apply it to $W\leftarrow\mathscr{S}$ and $v_1,\cdots,v_r$ where we defined above by
\begin{equation*}
C=\begin{pmatrix}
{v}_1 \\ 
{v}_2 \\ 
\cdots \\ 
{v}_n
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
G=C^T \mathrm{diag}\{\overbrace{1,\cdots,1}^{\text{first $r$ components}},0,\cdots,0\}C.
\end{equation*}

Then by claim $1$, given $w\in \mathscr{S}$, $w^TGw=0\iff $ $w$ is orthogonal to ${v}_i$, $1\le i\le r$. That is, "$(2)$ in your theorem does not hold for $G$ and $\mathscr{S}$" $\iff$ "exists $w\ne 0$, $w\in \mathscr{S}$ and $w$ is orthogonal to ${v}_i$, $1\le i\le r$".

On the other hand, by claim $2$,
"$(3)$ in your theorem does not hold for $G$ and $\mathscr{S}$" $\iff$ "$\operatorname{span}(G) \subseteq \mathscr S$ strictly".

That is, if the equivalence of
"exists $w\ne 0$, $w\in \mathscr{S}$ and $w$ is orthogonal to ${v}_i$, $1\le i\le r$"
and
"$\operatorname{span}(G) \subseteq \mathscr S$ strictly"
is verified, then "$\neg (2)$" $\iff$ "$\neg(3)$" can be implied
(where $\neg$ is negation),
and so is $(2)\iff (3)$.

Comment: Xiexie. What does this $A\oplus A^{\perp}=V$ mean? What's the notation of $\oplus$?

Comment: I don't understand "So to prove $(2)\iff (3)$, it suffices to prove: $\mathrm{span}({v}_1,\cdots,{v}_r)$ is contained in $W$ properly". What is W?

Comment: @Jonathen I have modified the statement you mentioned, and added at the end of the answer the reason we can reduce $(2)\iff (3)$ to this statement.  As for $A\oplus A^{\perp}=V$, $\oplus$ is the *direct sum*, and $A^{\perp}$ denotes the subspace $$ \{x\in V:\ x\cdot a=0,\ \forall a\in A\}$$. The proof for $A\oplus A^{\perp}=V$ can be found, for instance, in *Linear Algebra Done Right*, third edition, 6.47 "Direct sum of a subspace and its orthogonal complement". (Forgive me for not typing a solution. It is a bit lengthy but can be found on many textbooks.)

Comment: In the line below "Now we show the above statement.", do you mean $x \in W$? Currently it's $x \in W-A$ there.

Comment: @Jonathen  "The above statement" refers to the one in the quoted block: "Let $W$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, ${v}_1,\cdots,{v}_r$ are $r$ ($r\le n$) linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. "$\mathrm{span}({v}_1,\cdots,{v}_r)$ is contained in $W$ properly (i.e. $\mathrm{span}({v}_1,\cdots,{v}_r)\subseteq W$, $\mathrm{span}({v}_1,\cdots,{v}_r)\ne W$)" $\iff$ "exists $0\ne w\in W$, $w$ is orthogonal to ${v}_i$, $1\le i\le r$"."

Comment: "Now we show the above statement. Denote $A=\mathrm{span}({v}_1,\cdots,{v}_r)$.

$(\implies)$: Select $x\in W-A$." I think it should be Select $x \in W$.

Comment: ($\implies$) is "$\mathrm{span}({v}_1,\cdots,{v}_r)$ is contained in $W$ properly (i.e. $\mathrm{span}({v}_1,\cdots,{v}_r)\subseteq W$, $\mathrm{span}({v}_1,\cdots,{v}_r)\ne W$)" $\implies$ "exists $0\ne w\in W$, $w$ is orthogonal to ${v}_i$, $1\le i\le r$". So we selected an $x\in W-A$ and constructed $x_1$, $x_2$ as in my answer, and $x_2$ is a choice for $w$ s.t. $0\ne w\in W$, $w$ is orthogonal to ${v}_i$, $1\le i\le r$.  ($x\in W-A$ means $x\in W, x\notin A$.)

Comment: @Jonathen  If $x$ is not assumed to be *not in* $A$ then $x_2$ can be $0$ (if $x\in A$). So $x\notin A$ is necessary here.